# Outlook out of memory exception

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook

I am getting this error

> ```
> There is not enough free memory to run this program. Quit one or more
> programs, and then try again
> ```

while saving mail on local.

This error generally occurring on machine which have more than 40000 mails.
I am continuously parsing through 40000 mails.

Comment: **There is not enough free memory to run this program. Quit one or more programs, and then try again**

Comment: Just a wild guess here, but could it be that you are out of memory?

Comment: If you post some code then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: `foreach(var items in Mapifolderfolder.items){ (items as mail item).saveAs(filename+."msg")}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont use foreach for it - convert it to oldschool

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= Mapifolderfolder.items.Count; counter++)
{
   var item = Mapifolderfolder.items[counter];

   if ((item as MailItem) != null)
  { 
    .saveAs(filename+."msg")
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why this obscure change helps?

Comment: @Traubenfuchs not sure any more :) I have found the information in blogs or soemthing like this... The problem was with foreach and memory management

Comment: Those who developed the unchanging Office interop API (especially the OL one) many years ago must have been hard masochists.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs :) Anyway this constructions helped me. If the answer was helpful for you too - vote it up plese :)